# Get location of iPhone via GPS/IP

Tags: iphone, geolocation, gps, ip-geolocation

Im working on a application for which I need to decide in which country the user is. Which is the most accurate way to do this?

Should I use GPS or IP-adress?

What would be the pros/cons with each method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Apple's location services, which use several technologies (cell towers, WiFi hotspots, GPS, etc.) to determine their location. You can then find the country quite easily with a lookup of the GPS coordinates. I think this would be more accurate than by-IP lookups.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably easier if you go via ip address and use a geo ip lookup service.

For GPS the GPS unit needs to be turned on. I guess lots of people disable it for energy saving. If you just turn on GPS for your check the user needs to get a gps fix first which can be time consuming as well.